# C symbol name "rs_createGD" not in load table

Tags: r

Recent updates to R & RStudio on Gentoo have led to this problem across a number of programs I've run for a long time.

```
M <- cor(mtcars)
##  different color series
col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000","red","#FF7F00","yellow","white",
                           "cyan", "#007FFF", "blue","#00007F"))
col2 <- colorRampPalette(c("#67001F", "#B2182B", "#D6604D", "#F4A582", "#FDDBC7",
                           "#FFFFFF", "#D1E5F0", "#92C5DE", "#4393C3", "#2166AC", "#053061"))
col3 <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "white", "blue"))
col4 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000","red","#FF7F00","yellow","#7FFF7F",
                           "cyan", "#007FFF", "blue","#00007F"))
wb <- c("white","black")


par(ask = TRUE)


## different color scale and methods to display corr-matrix
corrplot(M, method = "number", col = "black", cl.pos = "n")
```

results in:

> par(ask = TRUE)
>   Error in .Call("rs_createGD") : 
>     C symbol name "rs_createGD" not in load table
>
> corrplot(M, method = "number", col = "black", cl.pos = "n")
>   Error in .Call("rs_createGD") : 
>     C symbol name "rs_createGD" not in load table

Google hasn't led me to any solution. Any ideas about what needs to be updated would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Experienced the same when upgraded R to 3.3 on Ubuntu. Couldn't exactly figure out how to fix the broken reference but removing rstudio and reinstalling the latest package from https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ resolved the issue.

Comment: It was a bit involved on Gentoo - unmasking the same version as it was marked 'testing' - but the solution worked fine.